# Adding new StoryBoard to UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, tabbar

I have many storyboards in my app. Earlier my app was not a `UITabBar` based app but now i decided to go in  a more `UITabBar` way. Now i want to add my storyboards to my `UITabBarController`. I opened one storyboard and embed that in the UITabBarController, but now i don't know how i can add other storybord's first `UIViewControllers` to my Tabbar. I don't have any tabBarController Property etc.

Any idea how i can add different story boards to one `UITabBarController`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move all in one storyboard, you should get reference to tab bar controller and add every storyboard's initial view controller programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my first question/concern would be why you have so many storyboards. Why not have all your view controllers on a single storyboard? If you had all your View Controllers on the same storyboard, then connecting them to UITabBarController is a trivial thing - control+drag a connection from the UITabBarController as many view controllers as you need.

If for some reason there is some requirement that you have view controllers distributed in multiple storyboards, then you should be able to load them programmatically in the following manner. In a subclass of UITabBarController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardHNameHere1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVCNameHere1"];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardHNameHere2" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [storyboard2 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVCNameHere2"];
    self.viewControllers = @[vc1,vc2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 for N8P's answer: implementing TabBarController using multiple storyboards.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let tabBar = UITabBarController()
    tabBar.viewControllers = self.getArrayOfViewControllers()
    self.customiseTabItems(tabBar: tabBar.tabBar)
    // set tabBar as root

    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

[see example](https://github.com/iggym/TabBarControllerMSB)